# exclude folder and file patterns for java compiler in idea intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javac, exclusionpath

I recently migrated from eclipse to intellij. I have many folders and files to be excluded from compilation. Eg. I have about 40-50 folders named 'test' containing class files and folders that needs to be excluded. I also need to exclude any class file whose name ends with *Test.java.

In eclipse the exclusion pattern is - **/test/** and **/*Test.java that I could set at project level.

In Intellij, I cannot find any equivalent thing that works. It is impractical for me to manually add 100s of folders and files individually at - 'Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Excludes'.

Does Intellij support exclusion pattern for folders and file like eclipse? Can you help me with above example - on what is the pattern and where to set it in intellij?

Please do not ask me to individually add all the test folders and files ending with Test.java to exclude. There are 100s of them. Looking for regex pattern like in eclipse.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the right thing, and move these files elsewhere If they're not suposed to be compiled, don't put them in the source folder. Test source files shouldn't be in the same source folder as production source files.

Comment: Sorry, Not the answer. It is not just about test folder or classes. There are many other folder patterns and classes I need to exclude. It is legacy code.

Can I do it in IntelliJ or not?

Comment: @Chetan there is no way to exclude files and folders by pattern from IntelliJ IDEA compiler.